# WSL fails to upgrade distro from verseion 1 to version 2

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having some problems upgrading WSL images from WSL1 to WSL2. I have been trying to upgrade a kali image which is on version 1:

[image]

When I try to change the version with `wsl --set-version kali-linux 2` I get the following error:

[image]

I am not sure what to do. If anyone has any ideas, they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try [this advice](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5508#issuecomment-744442821).

Comment: This means you have either not updated Windows 10 to a compatible version or you have not updated the Linux Kernel to the current version.  Have you followed the instructions on [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment